# What does putExtraData do in Kotlin Intent?

Tags: android, kotlin

I am trying to send an object (via intent ) of data class type and came across this method

`putExtraData` in Kotlin. ( Could not find a similar method in Java).

What does it do ? Can i send an object of this type using that method? I was wondering because i may avoid having to use Parcelable and Serializable if this is possible.

```
 data class Properties(val actionBarColor : Int){

 }
```

Comment: Maybe for future purposes.

Comment: Where have you found this method? `SupportActivity` or `Intent`?